# Typescript - unexpected sequence with setTimeout in combination with async and await

Tags: typescript, async-await

When I run this script, the output is different from what I expect: 1 through 4. Why is that?

```
const delay2 = async ( ms: number) => setTimeout( () => {
  console.log( '2 - timeout')
}, ms);

const mainAsync2 = async () => {
  console.log( '1 - before');
  await delay2( 2000);
  console.log( '3 - after');
}
mainAsync2()
.then( res => console.log( '4 - done'));
```

The output is:

> ```
> 1 - before
> 3 - after
> 4 - done
> 2 - timeout
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` by itself does not return a promise, so `await`ing it does nothing. It simply sets a timeout for `ms` milliseconds. Instead, you should make your `delay2` return a promise that resolves after `ms` milliseconds, for example:

```
const delay2 = async (ms: number) =>
    new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => { 
        console.log('2 - timeout');
        res();
    }, ms));
```